# How to compile recent PHP with old MySQL libraries from source?

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP 5.4.26 (FreeBSD); I am trying to use the old MySQL libraries.
Saw this command:

```
./configure --with-mysql=/path/to/mysql_config
```

Where do I put this command; it says that it is a compile time decision?

Comment: You run that command when you are building php from source.

Answer (score 1):

Note you'll need root privileges to do this. Download the source code from php.net. unzip it to a folder.

On a command line in the unzip folder:

./configure --with-mysql=/path/to/mysql_config

make

make test

make install

That will replace your current installation. Note that you will need to carefully research the configure options you want so you don't lose any functionality you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be complete, here is a tutorial for FreeBSD for using the old libraries and the new ones. Since they are separate.

[Using “new” PHP with “old” MySQL passwords](http://www.dalescott.net/accessing-old-mysql-server-using-new-php/)

Just in case that page disappears here are the steps for FreeBSD:

```
# pkg_delete php5-mysql
# cd /usr/ports/databases/php5-mysql
# make config  (uncheck support for mysqlnd)
# make install clean
```